# Cannot implicitly convert type with IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

So I'm chugging along on this MVC application and all is running smoothly.  I get up to fix a bite to eat and the next time I build I'm greeted with 4 of these errors:

```
> Error 16  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>
> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>
> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Keep in mind that there is actually something in IEnumerable<>, I just removed it.

This is the 2 classes where the errors are at

```
    public partial class PriceListController : Controller
    {

        [CanonicalUrlAttribute("PriceList")]
        [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
        [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 2)]
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();
            var viewModel = new PriceListViewModel() { PriceListAnimals = context.GetAnimalListForPriceList() };
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
        [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 2)]
        public virtual ActionResult List(string animal)
        {
            GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();

            var viewModel = new PriceListIndexViewModel() { AnimalPrices = context.GetPriceListByAnimal(animal) };
            return View(viewModel);
        }

    }
public partial class GalleryController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Gallery/
    [CanonicalUrlAttribute("Gallery")]
    [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
    [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 2)]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();
        var viewModel = new GalleryIndexViewModel() { GalleryAnimals = context.GetAnimalListForGallery() };
        return View(viewModel);
    }


    [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
    [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 2)]
    public virtual ActionResult List(string animal)
    {
        GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();

        var viewModel = new GalleryListViewModel() { GalleryImages = context.GetGalleryImageByAnimal(animal) };
        return View(viewModel);

    }

}
```

I've checked the DAL and Repository and no errors coming from there.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed some code around where the exception occurs?

Comment: IIS I assume? Try running the IISReset utility to reset the server (must be ran as administrator), then rebuild.

Comment: Hmm, can we maybe see more code? Where exactly is it throwing the exception?

Comment: Weird thing is it ran when I left for dinner but when I got back I got all these errors.

Comment: Does it show which line the exceptions occur on?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the same thing was in both the "from" and "to" System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>?

Comment: @PsychoCoder In my opinion please try checking that the viewmodel is using the same `class` IEnumerable the one you are passing.. in the current `view` you are trying to code. and also inheritance of parent class to child class does not work in the IEnumerable and List<T> .. so check that out also...   I hope that helps

Comment: Hash,I understand what you'e saying but all the conrollers arereturning exactly what I want. Gallery Controller it's likes24 & 35, PriceListConrollerit gives error on lines 25 & 36. It's rather odd that it could stop working wen it wasnt ouched at all. Before I went fr lunh I did a build and ran it with issues.

Comment: Got those errors resolved, it was my fault because I was calling the wrong methods from the DAL/Repository.

Comment: @PsychoCoder Since it's already solved, please answer your own question and mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest showing all error messages displayed because something that weird is usually an artifact of another easier to solve bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got those errors resolved, it was my fault because I was calling the wrong methods from the DAL/Repository.